# SlackにAPIで画像ファイルをアップロードできますか？

Tags: node.js, hubot

slackのapiを使ってpngファイルをアップロードしたいです。
以下のようなnodeのコードを書いて試してみていますがアップロード自体は成功しますがslackの方でtextとして認識されてしまいうまくいきません。

```
const api_url = 'https://slack.com/api/';
fs.readFile('./android_page_pr.png', function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
    options = {
        token: SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
        content: data,
        filetype: 'image',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        filename: 'android_page_pr.png',
        title: 'android_page_pr.png',
        channels: 'github-kiss'
    }
    request.post(api_url + 'files.upload', function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('Got response', error, body);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var json;
            try {
                json = JSON.parse(body);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            if (json.ok) {
                console.log('json ok');
            } else {
                console.log('json ng');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('status code: ' + response.statusCode);
        }
    }).form(options);
});
```

どなたか分かる方がいましたらご教示ください！

Comment: curlでならできました。これをnode.jsでやるにはどう書けば良いのか。

`curl -F file=@android_page_pr.png -F channels=#general -F token=hoge-hoge-fuga  https://slack.com/api/files.upload`

Comment: 自己解決しました。
http://iyuichi.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/06/14/195651

Comment: 自己解決した場合も http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer にあるように、解決方法を回答として軽くまとめていただくと他の人の役に立つかもしれません

Comment: ブログの方に書きましたが以下のプルリクが出されていて今回の事象が起きていることと関係あると思います。
https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/pull/112

なので自前でアップロードする部分を書きました。
https://gist.github.com/y16ra/e22bf71cd05b62d818a7a05ddd68b2ec#file-slack-file-upload-js